# How to add a gradient shadow to tableView cell similar to Apple Health app?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gradient

How can I customize a tableView cell to have a gradient shadow across the bottom of the cell similar to the orange tableView cells in the Health App.

[image]

I would like to make it as close to this as possible.

This is what I currently have, I've added the separation between the cells by using a white border and added a radius of 8 for the corners.

**What can I add to make the gradient?**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier: String = "stockCell"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!

    myCell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    myCell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    myCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    myCell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.86, green:0.25, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0).cgColor

    let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel

    myCell.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    myCell.layer.masksToBounds = true
    myCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    myCell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0

    myCell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    myCell.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe instead of casting a "gradient shadow" across the bottom of the cell, you just want the cell to have a background gradient from a lighter color on the top to a darker color in the bottom.

I usually use en extension of `UIView` for adding gradients to views:

```
extension UIView {
  func setGradient(colors: [CGColor]) {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = colors
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
  }
}
```

Then, try using something like this in your code:

```
myCell.setGradient([cgColorLight, cgColorDark])
```

This sometimes doesn't work if you do some custom drawing in your view's layers, but I believe it should be okay for your needs.

Comment: This solution works well, but the text in the cell is covered, how can this be fixed?

Comment: The gradient layer might be on top of the other layers. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Do you know of any better way I could add a space between my cell? Adding a white border around the cells just seems wrong. The other posts I've seen on this are a bit confusing; I really appreciate your help

Comment: I believe there isn't a specifically supported way to do this. Instead, I'd recommend you use UICollectionView. It specifically supports that functionality, and has many other features. I'm pretty sure that the Health app uses a collection view instead of a table view. By the way, remember to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both horizontal and vertical gradients with the following but define the following variables:

```
typealias GradientPoints = (startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint)

enum GradientOrientation {
case topRightBottomLeft
case topLeftBottomRight
case horizontal
case vertical

var startPoint: CGPoint {
    return points.startPoint
}

var endPoint: CGPoint {
    return points.endPoint
}

var points: GradientPoints {
    switch self {
    case .topRightBottomLeft:
        return (CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 1.0), CGPoint.init(x: 1.0, y: 0.0))
    case .topLeftBottomRight:
        return (CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint.init(x: 1, y: 1))
    case .horizontal:
        return (CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.5), CGPoint.init(x: 1.0, y: 0.5))
    case .vertical:
        return (CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 1.0))
    }
}
}
```

And create an extension for uiview as follows:

```
extension UIView{

func applyGradient(withColours colours: [UIColor], gradientOrientation orientation: GradientOrientation) {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradient.startPoint = orientation.startPoint
    gradient.endPoint = orientation.endPoint
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
}
```

Comment: @RelsonJames i didnt get you?

Answer (score -1):

Please add these lines in your cell class.

```
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor];
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Comment: That's Objective-C

Comment: Why would anyone just copy and paste a piece of code without looking at the question ?

Comment: @Rajesh yes you are absolutely right but you should at least add couple of lines (explanation) to your answer. I've seen many people who can't convert objective C code to Swift. Looks like someone already downvoted your answer, I wonder why!

Comment: I haven't seen comments like before. Ok, next time will provide the same.